# Conditional Types based on function input parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have a function:

```
function navigateOptions(currentScreenRoute: 'addGroup' | 'addGroupOnboarding', group: GroupEngagement) {
  const navigationKey = currentScreenRoute === 'addGroup' ? 'addGroupPeople' : 'addGroupQR';
  const params =
    currentScreenRoute === 'addGroup'
      ? {
          group,
          inviteCode: group.inviteCode,
          showGroupCreatedToast: true,
        }
      : {
          inviteCode: group.invite_code!,
        };

  return { navigationKey, params };
}
```

I want the return type to either resolve as:

```
{ navigationKey: 'addGroupPeople', params: { group: GroupEngagement, inviteCode: string, showGroupCreatedToast: boolean }}
```

OR

```
{ navigationKey: 'addGroupQR', { inviteCode: string }}
```

The issue I have is that `navigationKey` is becoming a `string` and `params` is becoming a union of the two types mentioned above.  I want the types to be determined based on the `currentScreenRoute` and pick one or the other to show as the type.

I believe I might need to use Conditional Types but can't determine how to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the code is currently written, there is no link between the `navigationKey` and `params` variables, even though we can obviously see that in practice both are implemented with a ternary that is solely dependent on `currentScreenRoute` in both cases.

You can get close to the type inferrence you want out of the box by just composing your full objects within the conditionals themselves, instead of as separate pieces

```
type GroupEngagement = {
  inviteCode: string;
  // ...
};

function navigateOptions(
  currentScreenRoute: 'addGroup' | 'addGroupOnboarding',
  group: GroupEngagement
) {
  const navigationKey: 'addGroupPeople' | 'addGroupQR' = currentScreenRoute === 'addGroup' ? 'addGroupPeople' : 'addGroupQR';

  if (navigationKey === 'addGroupPeople') {
    return {
      navigationKey,
      params: {
        group,
        inviteCode: group.inviteCode,
        showGroupCreatedToast: true,
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    return {
      navigationKey,
      params: {
        inviteCode: group.inviteCode,
      }
    }
  }
}

/*
Return type:
{
    navigationKey: "addGroupPeople";
    params: {
        group: GroupEngagement;
        inviteCode: string;
        showGroupCreatedToast: boolean;
    };
} | {
    navigationKey: "addGroupQR";
    params: {
        inviteCode: string;
        group?: undefined;
        showGroupCreatedToast?: undefined;
    };
}
*/
```

As there are no types expressed upfront, TypeScript attempts to infer the type of `params`, and its most sensible guess is that both `params` objects are of the same type but with some optional properties (seeing as `inviteCode` appears on both objects and is of the same type)

---

A more robust solution would be to bake these distinct definitions into some types and use a discriminated union structure to describe the options available to be returned.

```
type AddGroupPeopleNavigationOption = {
  navigationKey: 'addGroupPeople',
  params: {
    group: GroupEngagement;
    inviteCode: GroupEngagement['inviteCode'];
    showGroupCreatedToast: true
  }
}
type AddGroupQrNavigationOption = {
  navigationKey: 'addGroupQR';
  params: {
    inviteCode: GroupEngagement['inviteCode'];
  }
}
type NavigationOption = AddGroupPeopleNavigationOption | AddGroupQrNavigationOption

function navigateOptions(
  currentScreenRoute: 'addGroup' | 'addGroupOnboarding',
  group: GroupEngagement
): NavigationOption {
  const navigationKey: NavigationOption['navigationKey'] = currentScreenRoute === 'addGroup' ? 'addGroupPeople' : 'addGroupQR';

  if (navigationKey === 'addGroupPeople') {
    // TypeScript knows the type of params here should be AddGroupQrNavigationOption['params']
    return {
      navigationKey,
      params: {
        group,
        inviteCode: group.inviteCode,
        showGroupCreatedToast: true,
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    // TypeScript knows the type of params here should be AddGroupPeopleNavigationOption['params']
    return {
      navigationKey,
      params: {
        inviteCode: group.inviteCode,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you attempt to provide a `params` object which does not conform to its inferred type definition (based on the value of `navigationKey`) you will now get an error.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gTgewK5gKIDsDmBDTEC2E6wUAvFAN4BQUUAlugG53AQDCCAJhAFxQDOwOA0xUAvgG4qVAPQyoAWiXKVqteo2atS6QDMk6AMbA6CdFHTZmOVgHkwJs-wCMAChpRDSOHCLAAyoa%20RABKyKx8AOTYnJzwyGCRUAA%20UNGx8Si26ABGCNhwnCKRADQemIgofJloWLgEflQAlJQehk4kltbYjugA0hAgZJ7evsSBwehhSKxkpOTpcZWJUAD8aTFLCQAKEAhgADYQSVGbNQCKIZFStO3oglBgBdj4-GQet6N%20ExCh4dDzBZnZaRD60NatcFQ8EVBJlaHQhjMVgcbh8WEoAB0SJY7C4EHhCPB-AAFggAO41Ni%20HoQTgAFXygj4QiQBLBULEHKgfGoRPBOJR%20PRy2xTFxqPZ-Mk0lovmA3nMFAsVjoNlM-UGJUez1eUBlXNk8m0JtNZvUegMxg1Ku6dgcGv4ACZ3J8fN8gr8pv9ThkQSkNn6Etk8gUilhSuVltVlhgcHhCMRmpDPB1bWqehqBiBfVsULt9kckqlFhcrsMvO7xp6-jMAfNA3mVutS8sC4djjzG2XrrL6LooK4uhnetm5kCg-m9h3Ii0%20eD5YqU1Dh%20qzNnCVCnnAXvxedzaBiwJvEeKhWioEexci8dwT1DSRSqTTWAymcAWXA2ff9WCubR-ygCADn4aB5zlCAFTgJVuVXTN1y1blt13fd%20UFW9eEvUV0MlH9AIAjwuUNORFHNMjyM0aRQEgKAAEFJzAdsjgAOVVNd0HsXphnnODR0GXMaiY45CWQ15UJhaNYFjOoEz8G4BTPDCYwSON6kTYAAG1Ihw-FIgAXXk2hH0pZZqQgWk32wZkoFZCBCPEKhqOgeim3OOBWLtDVOJtcgeLY%20DNRzbtlkuXtaFEvdl3oRTJWUlBVNk4gtJ07h9PkojHPAaAPJHLyHTMYYXME6cWP83pvIK1IipC9yyry3pLSMLjeIgCr7gAZldEYqwCGtvTrAT-RLYFg1yfJCmKQkjzi2p4waJMmj4HL2LalM7geXis34qBloCtqtM2hCQH0isvmrSZplmQFgoSJIWxGqdC07QaElCqQPDoAchzqo7xxux6ZznMFF2gqLaEOwKfwi8SESPH9aBSzCr0R%20GBDJEyEjMizGSsj8bK-KVoXw38CNoYDQKikGYIRCGNyQ3VIvA08b1irCEmvCV8Twv97LEIA)